# How to use $_GET & $_POST in a function properly?

Tags: php, post, get

I have just came across a problem today for which I couldn't find a possible solution. I'll try to explain it to you guys.

Lets say we create a function, where we will check if the provided Field is set or not. It can be submitted either with $_POST or $_GET. Let's see an example for this theory:

```
// The field is the name of the submitted form element, the method should be either POST or GET

        function isset_test($field, $method)
        {
            if ($method === 'POST')
            {
                if (isset($_POST[$field]) === true)
                {
                    echo 'POST field isset';
                }
            }
            elseif ($method === 'GET')
            {
                if (isset($_GET[$field]) === true)
                {
                    echo 'GET field isset';
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see in this example the code should be working just fine, however it is almost a duplicated code.

This is the reason I was thinking about: can we just get the value of `$method` (which should be either POST or GET) and place it in the code acting as a variable? Something like this (but I know its not working):

```
// The field is the name of the submitted form element, the method should be either POST or GET

        function isset_test($field, $method)
        {
            if ($method === 'POST' || $method === 'GET')
            {
                if (isset($_ . $method . [$field]) === true)
                {
                    echo $method . ' field isset';
                }
            }
        }
```

This above code does not work, because PHP looks at the `$method` as a String. Is there any solution, so PHP will take those as a real `$_POST[]` or `$_GET[]` variable?

EDIT:

I'm actually not okay with both of the fields, so I do not want to use $_REQUEST. I'm just trying to create a function which can be used for both of the request types, and call one and the other when it's needed.

Comment: The [third note on this page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php#refsect1-language.variables.superglobals-notes) is relevant. In other words, you need to access `$_GET` and `$_POST` directly. Anyway, this is not a worthwhile thing to use your time on; just access them as in the first code example and be done with it.

Comment: Why would you want to not use REQUEST and create separate functions for GET and POST? And then worry about duplicate code?

Comment: @Sverri M. Olsen I actually do intend to create more functions for checking user submitted data with much longer codes. This is why I'm actually looking for a solution which could reduce the code size. Do you think I should stick with the first example or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Using $_REQUEST gets GET or POST

this way you can check

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["variable_name"])) {
    // This will give GET and POST values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with the field being in either `$_POST` or `$_GET`, just use `$_REQUEST`. It contains the data from both post and get.

Answer (score 0):

What you write in your function, I am going do a little bit of modification on that.

```
Here is my coding:


        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
            {
              if (isset($_POST[$field]))
                 {
                   echo 'POST field isset';
                 }
            }

        else
           {
               if (isset($_GET[$field]))
                  {
                     echo 'GET field isset';
                  }
           }
```

**$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']**  is help you to check the request method type.

**OR**

You can try this also:

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
      {

         echo 'POST field isset';

      }

   else
      {

          echo 'GET field isset';

      }



Hope it will work
Thank you 
Dron
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
function isset_test($field)
{
    if (isset($_POST[$field]))
    {
            echo 'POST field isset';
    }
    elseif (isset($_GET[$field]))
    {
        echo 'GET field isset';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Neither GET or POST';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

PHP has [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) that allow you to access `$$method[$field]`.

However, in your specific case, you can also just use `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: Will I be safe and efficient if I use variable variables? Does it have any disadvantages?

Comment: Using variable variables to access superglobals *does not work*. Read the documentation.

Comment: @Victor Here you go: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php#refsect1-language.variables.superglobals-notes